# get current state of kendo scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, state, scheduler

How can I get the current state of a kendo scheduler after some edit operation, especially the number of items and their state (start, end etc.)? For example, if I remove an item, I want to know how many items are left. I do not know where this info is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the dataBound event of the scheduler, because the event is called after every change of the scheduler datasource.
Use Layonez' code to inspect the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

You talking about [sheduler dataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/schedulerdatasource).

You can receive it in outer scope by jquery:

```
var data = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource;
```

Or in inner event scope:

```
var data = this.dataSource.data();
```